# What is a word in the context of bitsets?

Tags: java, bitmap, lucene, bit-manipulation

The [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) refers to the array of longs underlying a BitSet implementation as "words" and each long is a word.

This seems straight forward, until you see the constructor for [Lucene's OpenBitSet](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/util/OpenBitSet.html)

```
BitSet(long[] bits, int numWords)
```

If each long was a word then

```
numWords  == bits.length
```

Reading the documentation further, it seems to say that each word is the number of longs being used, this further confuses me because if they are not all being used - then only the ones at the end of the array could be the ones not being used - in which case why not simply make a copy `BitSet` with the desired longs..

Could someone please clarify the concept of a word in the context of `BitSets`?

Comment: Not all of them might be in use, but making sure that the array has _exactly_ the right size requires an O(n) copy every time you start a new word.  Having some words not in use -- e.g. doubling the array size every time you exceed the length you've been using -- has better asymptotics.